# AWS Aurora Mysql failover

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, failover

I have two AWS aurora MySQL instances, one writer and other reader. I want to downsize my writer instance from t3 medium to t3 small. However, for some reason, I don't want my writer instance to failover. Once my writer instance is downsized, I will then downsize my reader instance as well. Can someone guide me with the solution?

regards

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more instance of size t3.small and do failover to this new instance.So that it will become writer and you can delete the older instance of size t3.medium.Downtime will be very minimal.